Why git help does nothing on Windows?
On a quite fresh Windows 11 installation, if I try to view git help from the command line I get nothing, for example (using Git Bash):
user@machine MINGW64 /d/src
$ git help -w config

user@machine MINGW64 /d/src
$ 

So it's just returning me back to the prompt without any output and without opening the git help file on a browser. What's wrong?

The default browser for .html files needs to be configured on Windows. This can be done and verified by attempting to open any .html file using File Explorer, for example the Git help files located in C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\doc\git-doc. If the default browser has been configured the file will open directly into the browser, otherwise there will be a popup dialog asking to choose the program with options for 'Just once' and 'Always'. On a fresh installation if you have never selected 'Always' the default browser has not been configured if not manually set otherwise.
